# Where can I find a table's segment in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a lot of tables in dba_tables (or dba_objects). How can I find which segments belongs to a certain table?

I looked at dba_segments, but there is no information about the tables.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but this might help: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schema005.htm

Comment: dba_segments has the table name in the `segment_name` column. Just filter by `segment_type = 'TABLE'`.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle 11g has deferred segment creation feature.
http://tkyte.blogspot.ru/2011/02/deferred-segment-creation.html

So no records in dba_segments can be.